# Drupal CKEditor custom styles

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I added custom styles to my CKEditor in Drupal however I can only select one style at a time.

[image]

For example here I want the element (h1) to have both classes (titre and fancy) not just one of them. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple classes in one style, like :

```
h1.fancy.titre|Titre fancy.
```

The help text for the field actually specifies this :

> Entrer une ou plusieurs classes sur chaque ligne dans le format element.classA.classB|Libellé.

So while you can't select multiple styles for the same text, you can define styles that apply multiple classes. It's a little bit repetitive, but you'd need :

```
h1.titre|Titre.
h1.fancy|Fancy.
h1.fancy.titre|Titre fancy.
```

Comment: yep I know but there's plenty of combinations so this would not work

Comment: you could try using <span> elements to define styles, since they can wrap other elements, but it would be best to properly define the styles that your users need. it could also be a sign that your custom styles are too complicated -- HTML provides semantic elements, styling those elements properly should be enough for users to style their text. if you need 20 additional styles, it may result in content that is difficult to read.